# Writing class object to file using streams

Tags: c++, string, wofstream, wifstream

I have this code to serialize/deserialize class objects to file, and it seems to work.
However, I have two questions.

1. What if instead two `wstring`'s (as I have now) I want to have one `wstring` and one `string` member
   variable in my class? (I think in such case my code won't work?).
2. Finally, below, in main, when I initialize `s2.product_name_= L"megatex";` if instead of megatex I write something in Russian say (e.g., s2.product_name_= L"логин"), the code doesn't work anymore as intended.

What can be wrong? Thanks.

Here is code:

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
using namespace std;

// product
struct Product
{
    double price_;
    double product_index_;
    wstring product_name_;
    wstring other_data_;

    friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const Product& p)
    {
         return os << p.price_ << endl
                  << p.product_index_ << endl
                  << p.product_name_ << endl  
                  << p.other_data_ << endl;
    }

    friend wistream& operator>>(std::wistream& is, Product& p)
    {
        is >> p.price_ >> p.product_index_;
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        getline(is,p.product_name_);
        getline(is,p.other_data_);

        return is;
    }
};

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Product s1,s2;

    s1.price_ = 100;
    s1.product_index_ = 0;
    s1.product_name_= L"flex";
    s1.other_data_ = L"dat001";

    s2.price_ = 300;
    s2.product_index_ = 2;
    s2.product_name_= L"megatex";
    s2.other_data_ = L"dat003";

    // write
    wofstream binary_file("c:\\test.dat",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
    binary_file << s1 << s2;
    binary_file.close();

    // read
    wifstream binary_file2("c:\\test.dat");

    Product p;
    while (binary_file2 >> p)
    {
        if(2 == p.product_index_){
            cout<<p.price_<<endl;
            cout<<p.product_index_<<endl;
            wcout<<p.product_name_<<endl;
            wcout<<p.other_data_<<endl;
        }
    }

    if (!binary_file2.eof())
         std::cerr << "error during parsing of input file\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Ok \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What if instead two wstring's (as I have now) I want to have one
>   wstring and one string member variable in my class? (I think in such
>   case my code won't work?).

There are an inserter defined for `char *` for any `basic_ostream` (`ostream` and `wostream`), so you can use the result of `c_str()` member function call for the `string` member. For example, if the `string` member is `other_data_`:

```
 return os << p.price_ << endl
           << p.product_index_ << endl
           << p.product_name_ << endl  
           << p.other_data_.c_str() << endl;
```

The extractor case is more complex, since you'll have to read as `wstring` and the convert to `string`. The most simple way to do this is just reading as `wstring` and then narrowing each character:

```
wstring temp;
getline(is, temp);
p.other_data_ = string(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

I'm not using locales in this sample, just converting a sequence of bytes (8 bits) to a sequence of words (16 bits) for output and the opposite (truncating values) for input. That is OK if you are using ASCII chars, or using single-byte chars and you don't require an specific format (as Unicode) for output.

Otherwise, you will need handle with `locale`s. locale gives cultural contextual information to interpret the string (remember that is just a sequence of bytes, not characters in the sense of letters or symbols; the map between the bytes and what symbol represents is defined by the `locale`). `locale` is not an very easy to use concept (human culture isn't too). As you suggest yourself, it would be better make first some investigation about how it works.

Anyway, the idea is:

1. Identify the charset used in string and the charset used in file (Unicode or utf-16).
2. Convert the `string`s from original charset to Unicode using `locale` for output.
3. Convert the `wstring`s read from file (in Unicode) to `string`s using `locale`.

> Finally, below, in main, when I initialize s2.product_name_=
>   L"megatex"; if instead of megatex I write something in Russian say
>   (e.g., `s2.product_name_= L"логин"`), the code doesn't work anymore as
>   intended.

When you define an array of `wchar_t` using `L""`, you'are not really specifying the string is Unicode, just that the array is of chars, not wchar_t. I suppose the intended working is `s2.product_name_` store the name in Unicode format, but the compiler will take every `char` in that string (as without `L`) and convert to `wchar_t` just padding with zeros the most significant byte. Unicode is not good supported in the C++ standard until C++11 (and is still not really too supported). It works just for ASCII characters because they have the same codification in Unicode (or UTF-8).

For using the Unicode characters in a static string, you can use escape characters: `\uXXXX`. Doing that for every not-English character is not very comfortable, I know. You can found a list of Unicode characters in multiple sites in the web. For example, in the Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get much of what you meant. Could you maybe explain that in a more easy to understand way? Thanks.

Comment: What part? first, second or both?

Comment: Added samples trying to do easier

Comment: Ok, thanks. So 1st part of my question, is achievable? What about the locales you mentioned last time?
The 2nd question, I don't get much: how/where to add the \uXXXX characters?

I feel I will post separatelty or study separately how to handle Unicode in C++ and then proceed with my example, otherwise it is getting too confusing.

Comment: I've tried to extend the answer to give more information. But not too much about locales at this moment, sorry!